# LinkedIn New Developer Program API Changes - Will company share be available?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

[In this post](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) from LinkedIn they mention the open APIs **will still support sharing content with the Company API**, but if you look further in their [Developer Program Transition Guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) they say the only endpoints available will be

- Profile API — `/v1/people/~`
- Share API — `/v1/people/~/shares`
- Companies API — `/v1/companies/{id}`

Does that mean that `/v1/companies/{id}/shares` won't be available? I find this misleading and could not find an answer anywhere else. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question -- I have the same confusion. My interpretation is that the `/v1/companies/{id}/shares` **will still be available**, because:

1. The [Transition FAQ](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/transition-faq) says:

> Finally, if you still find you have questions about what will be possible after May 12th, please take a moment to check out our [Apigee API console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) and browse the [updated documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs) on the Developer website.

2. the [Apigee API console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) still shows the `/v1/companies/{id}/shares` endpoint
3. the [updated documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs) for [company pages](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages) still shows the `/v1/companies/{id}/shares` [create a company share](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_share) endpoint

Comment: They could have made all the info clear and available in only one place, couldn't they? Thanks Rob, if no one else give a definitive answer I'll accept yours.

Comment: Indeed, @bakkay!  It would also be helpful if the docs were consistent in this case.   And it would also be helpful if they would list which endpoints are available in the Developer Program prior to May 12, 2015 that will no longer be available after May 12.

Answer (score 1):

I found that linkedin no longer supports any access to the company api endpoint for other than the registered company owner. Here is the reply for a request to the basic profile:

```
LinkedIn::Errors::AccessDeniedError: (403): Member 6xxxxx4 does not have permission to get company 7xxxx1
```